# Google Apps Script - Create PDf from Spreadsheet produces pdf of Google sign in page

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script

Need some help, am somewhat confused!

I have written a google apps script for a spreadsheet, accessed from a custom menu, that should create a pdf of the spreadsheet page, and save it in my google drive. The code executes OK and a pdf is created, but all I get is a pdf of a google sign in page (for sheets). I am the owner of the spreadsheet and the drive folder and working in my Google Apps for Education account. If I try the full url (theurl) in a browser, I get the pdf I am after, so that works OK, so must be something to do with the blob or authorisation, but I can't see why? I must be missing something obvious. I have tried some of the authorisation code blocks I have seen but these just freeze the script. Any help much appreaciated. Tim

See attached for pdf output  [Order](http://tsah.co.uk/tsah/Order-0004---2015-04-06-1227.pdf)

Here is my code:

```
function spreadsheetToPDF(){

  var key = '14vZzkfMj9XSk4pgbQc78s1pBmsakHABJk7_MSX6j7xs';  //docid

  var index = 0;  //sheet gid / number


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ActiveSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Order Form');

  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'-'HHmm");
  var supp_name = ActiveSheet.getRange("C12").getValue();  //supplier
  var plainonum = ActiveSheet.getRange("C5").getValue();  //order number
  var onum = ('0000' + plainonum ).slice(-4);  //sets leading zeros to order number
  var description = ActiveSheet.getRange("C18").getValue();  //description

  var name = 'Order-' + onum +'-' + supp_name + '-' + description + '-' + timestamp + '.pdf';  //makes pdf filename

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  //ensures everything on spreadsheet is "done"

  //make the pdf from the sheet
  var theurl = 'https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/'
  + key 
  + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
  + '&size=A4'
  + '&portrait=true'
  + '&fitw=true'       // fit to width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'
  + '&gridlines=false'
  + '&fzr=false'      // do not repeat frozen rows on each page
  + '&gid='
  + index;       //the sheet's Id

  var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl);
  var pdf = docurl.getBlob().setName(name).getAs('application/pdf');

  //save the pdf to the folder on drive
  try {
      folder = DocsList.getFolder('Orders');
    } 
  catch (e) {
       folder = DocsList.createFolder('Orders');
    }
  folder.createFile(pdf);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks both, and to Zig for pointing me in the right direction. After a bit of digging around I found a script on labnol.org - doing something quite different but showing the oAuth authorisation part.

I needed a new variable

```
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
```

and then to add some more code to the docurl variable

```
var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
```

This provided the required authorisation for when the spreadsheet is not public.

Working function:

```
    function spreadsheetToPDF(){

      var key = '14vZzkfMj9XSk4pgbQc78s1pBmsakHABJk7_MSX6j7xs';  //docid

      var index = 0;  //sheet gid / number


      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var ActiveSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Order Form');

      var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'-'HHmm");
      var supp_name = ActiveSheet.getRange("C12").getValue();  //supplier
      var plainonum = ActiveSheet.getRange("C5").getValue();  //order number
      var onum = ('0000' + plainonum ).slice(-4);  //sets leading zeros to order number
      var description = ActiveSheet.getRange("C18").getValue();  //description

      var name = 'Order-' + onum +'-' + supp_name + '-' + description + '-' + timestamp + '.pdf';  //makes pdf filename

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();  //ensures everything on spreadsheet is "done"

      //make the pdf from the sheet
      var theurl = 'https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/'
      + key 
      + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
      + '&size=A4'
      + '&portrait=true'
      + '&fitw=true'       // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'
      + '&gridlines=false'
      + '&fzr=false'      // do not repeat frozen rows on each page
      + '&gid='
      + index;       //the sheet's Id

      var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
      var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
      var pdf = docurl.getBlob().setName(name).getAs('application/pdf');

      //save the file to folder on Drive
  var fid = '0B1quMlsbdFZyfkZRaWFQZVZLdFNDcC1hZGVqM25NNDhZblhVZktjamJLTVBXRXk5aThtcXc';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fid);
  folder.createFile(pdf);

    }
```

Must go and do some reading up about this!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`, you can get a reference to the file using the **DriveApp** class.

[Google DriveApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)

The problem with using this method, is that I don't know of a way to do something like fit the PDF to one page, other than formatting the Sheet before it's saved.

Also, the **DocsList** class is now deprecated.

Maybe try something like this:

```
function createPDF() {

  var fileToUse = 'FileID';
  //Logger.log('fileToUse: ' + fileToUse);

  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileToUse); 
  var theBlob = templateFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');

  var folderID = folderToSaveTo;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

   //newFile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);

};
```

Comment: How would I get all the creation variables that I get when using the fetch method?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that with the code I gave.  That's the downside to that option.  You might need a template spreadsheet, that you transfer the data to, then create the PDF from the template.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is by design. You are attempting to bypass user validation. If you look at the docs you will find getAs. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getAs(String)

Comment: So how do I overcome that? I have followed code that others appear to have used successfully, but it is not working for me?

Comment: The urlFetch method would only work if 1) the spreadsheet is public or 2) you supply the appropiate oauth2 parameters like the accessToken. Ive seen other s.o. qas that cover how to do this.