# creating a PDF file with Google Sheets and Google Apps Script

Tags: email, pdf, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a PDF file using data from Google Sheets. I've searched for a solution without using Google Docs as I have made my template in Google Sheets, but none of them seems to have this method as they usually use Google Docs for in-between to these two platforms. So, is there any way I could create a PDF using both template and data in Google Sheets without using Google Docs?

Comment: have  you tried googling your question?

Comment: Check this script on creating a PDF of a Google Spreadsheet file  & then saving it to a Google Drive folder at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29473278/15384825 answer your question. Or you can check this other answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39706318/15384825 (Only create a PDF of a specific Sheet in a spreadsheet file then save it to a Google Drive folder).